# Pushing object into vector to manually manipulate for objected orientated program

Tags: c++, class, oop, vector, methods

I have a project for one of my classes and I'm stuck and desperately need help. I'm creating an object orientated program for  student admissions.

- There is he base class student which has two child classes, domesticstudent and internationalstudent.
- There is one another class Toeflscore.
- The program reads a .txt file for private member variables of student - string firstname, string lastname, float cgpa, and int researchscore.
- The child classes also have a private member variable - string province for domestic and string country for international.

I have to basically manipulate the variables and arrange then in specific ways manually with no library. I'm stuck on trying to add the member variables to a vector.

I've been trying to define the vector inside the class and push objects onto it using get and set functions it doesn't seem to be working, I've tried friend as well. I'm pretty new if someone good point me in the right direction it would be appreciated. I'm using an older version of C++

```
setpopulate(student& s1, vector<student> temp) //friend
{
  temp.push_back(s1.FirstName)
}
```

```
  string line;
  student s1;
  ifstream domesticFile("domestic-stu.txt");
  if(!domesticFile.is_open()) {
    cout << "Unable to open file domestic-stu.txt" << endl;
    return -1;
  }
  getline(domesticFile, line);
  cout << "File format: " << line << endl;

  int stu_count = 1;
  while( getline(domesticFile, line) ) {

    istringstream ss(line);

    string firstName, lastName, province, s_cgpa, s_researchScore;
    float cgpa;
    int researchScore;

    getline(ss, firstName, ',');
    getline(ss, lastName, ',');
    getline(ss, province, ',');
    getline(ss, s_cgpa, ',');

    cgpa = atof(s_cgpa.c_str());
    getline(ss, s_researchScore, ',');
    researchScore = atoi(s_researchScore.c_str());

    s1.setFirstName(firstName);
    s1.setLastName(lastName);
    s2.setProvince(province);
    s1.setcgpa(cgpa);
    s1.setresearchscore(researchScore);
    //print the student info to the screen
    cout << "Domestic student " << stu_count << " " << firstName << " " 
     << lastName << " from " << province << " province has cgpa of "
     << cgpa << ", and research score of " << researchScore << endl;
    stu_count++;
  }
  domesticFile.close();
```

```
#ifndef STUDENT_HPP_
#define STUDENT_HPP_
using namespace std;
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<vector>
#include<iomanip>


class student
{ 
 public:

 student();
student(string newFirstName,string newLastName,float newcgpa,int newresearchscore,vector<student> x);


/*student(const student& copy)
{
  string newFirstName,string newLastName,float newcgpa,int newresearchscore)
};*/

 string getFirstName() const;
 void setFirstName(string newFirstName) ;

 string getLastName()const ;
 void setLastName(string newLastName);

 
 float getcgpa() const;
 void setcgpa(float newcgpa);

 int getresearchscore() const;
 void setresearchscore(int newresearchscore);

 friend void setpopulate(student& s1, string vector<student> temp);
 
 void setvector(string vector<student> x);
 string getvector() const;
 

friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const student& obj);

friend string compareFirstName(const student& s1, const student& s2);
friend string compareLastName(const student& s1, const student& s2);
friend float comparecgpa(const student& s1, const student& s2);
friend int compareresearchscore(const student& s1, const student& s2);

friend bool operator ==(const student& s1, const student& s2);
friend bool operator >(const student& s1, const student& s2);
friend bool operator <(const student& s1, const student& s2);


 private:
 string FirstName;
 string LastName;
 float cgpa;
 int researchscore;
 vector<student> temp;

 

};
#endif
```

Comment: "it doesnt seem to be working" - that is not an adequate description.  What specifically doesn't work?  Which line of code?  Does it compile?  Does it run and crash?  Does it run and give the wrong output?

Comment: [`static`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) may help you out. Right now each `student` contains its own list of `students`

Comment: `void setvector(string vector<student> x);` huh? Also what's the purpose of the student vector int the `student` class? I'd excect the students to be read into a vector that's located somewhere else. Furthermore if you want to put students of different types into the same vector, you need to use pointers: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<student>>` (requires `student` to have a virtual destructor)

Comment: I put the vector<student> temp inside the class hoping i could store private members inside it to arrange. I was initially just trying to store the all string FirstName members inside it used member and friend functions inside the class to sort. My problem is Im unable to store anything using the setvector() function and just am getting syntax errors. Would it be better to create multiple vectors to hold each data type and private member variable?

Comment: I think `std::vector<Student>` should be global and it would store all the `Student` objects. Each student can be domestic or international (so there will be a category for that in the file). Each student "has-a" TOEFL score. So, inside `Student` there should be `ToeflScore` object as a member (association). For comparing `Student` objects you can use `operator==`. Does that help?

Comment: "My problem is Im unable to store anything using the setvector()" The class shouldn't have anything like `setvector` in the first place. No, multiple vectors to hold each data type would be a very, very big mistake. You should have a vector of students, just not anywhere inside `class Student`.